# Documenting Python Bottle API With Custom Decorators/Attributes

Tags: python, documentation, asp.net-web-api, bottle

I am working on an API (using Python Bottle framework) that will be used by a variety of clients.  In doing so, I am trying to kill 2 birds with one stone regarding documentation.  What I would like to do is create some type of decorator/attribute where I can describe each public route of the API.  Then, I have a route that loops through all of the other routes, and gathers this information (description, input, output...).  This information is returned as a JSON array - where it is rendered in a user friendly html format.

Gathering the route info is easy:

```
@route('/api-map',method=['GET'])
def api_map():
    api_methods = []
    for route in app.routes:
        if route.rule != "/api-map":
            ##TODO: get custom attribute from routes function with description, inputs, outputs...
            api_methods.append({"route":route.rule,"desc":"?"})

    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return {"apiMap":api_methods}
```

But I am stuck at how to achieve the documentation.  Below is conceptually what I am trying to pull off, where 'svmdoc' is an attribute where I put this info:

```
@route('/token',method=['GET'])
@svmdoc(desc="Generates Token",input="username and password")
def getToken():
    #TODO token magic
```

Any suggestions on how to implement this approach?  Does something like this already exist that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use normal docstrings and create a template to render your api docs in a readable way

**bottle0_template.tpl**

```
<table>
<tr style="background-color:#CCCFDF"><th colspan="2">API Documentation</th></tr>
<tr style="background-color:#CCCFDF"><th>ENDPOINT</th><th>DESC</th></tr>
 % for color,resource in zip(colors,routes) :
   % docx = resource.callback.__doc__.replace("\n","<br/>")
   <tr style="background-color:{{ color }}"><td>{{ resource.rule }}</td><td> {{! docx }} </td></tr>
 % end
 </table>
```

then change your file to

**bottle0.py**

```
from bottle import route, run,app,template
from itertools import cycle
docs_exclude = "/api-doc","/api-map"

@route('/api-doc',method=['GET'])
def api_doc():
    colors = cycle('#FFFFFF #CCCFDF'.split())
    routes = filter(lambda x:x.rule not in docs_exclude,app[0].routes)
    return template("bottle0_template",colors=colors,routes=routes)


@route('/token')
def token():
    '''
    grant api token

    params:
      username: string,username of user
      password: string, password of user
    '''
    return "ASD!@#!#!@#"

@route('/userinfo')
def userinfo():
    '''
    grant api token

    params:
      - username: string,username of user to retrieve data for
      - code: string, api access token
    '''
    return json.dumps({"name":"bob"})

#print app[0].routes[1].callback.__doc__#api-doc
run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

then go to `http://localhost:8080/api-doc`